# Installing MySQL-python causes command 'clang' failed with exit status 1 on Mac OS 10.13.15

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have installed tools via xcode-select --install but still show the following error while doing `pip install MySQL-python`

```
Building wheels for collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MySQL-python ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/vaibhavmule/Envs/switchidea/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/p6/0v0bflxn3t399_qdpnm2z7hc0000gn/T/pip-install-SD9Cgh/MySQL-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/p6/0v0bflxn3t399_qdpnm2z7hc0000gn/T/pip-wheel-g6C50k --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7
  clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
  _mysql.c:36:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
  #include "my_config.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for MySQL-python
  Running setup.py clean for MySQL-python
Failed to build MySQL-python
django-model-utils 3.0.0 has requirement Django>=1.8, but you'll have django 1.6.7 which is incompatible.
faker 0.8.16 has requirement six>=1.10, but you'll have six 1.6.1 which is incompatible.
django-phonenumber-field 2.0.0 has requirement Django>=1.11, but you'll have django 1.6.7 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, opbeat, olefile, Pillow, pyzmq, contextlib2, raven, simplejson, South, sqlparse, wheel, django-sendfile, httplib2, pytz, twilio, phonenumberslite, babel, django-phonenumber-field, django-twilio, text-unidecode, python-dateutil, Faker, factory-boy, waitress, beautifulsoup4, WebOb, webtest, django-webtest, coverage
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/vaibhavmule/Envs/switchidea/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/p6/0v0bflxn3t399_qdpnm2z7hc0000gn/T/pip-install-SD9Cgh/MySQL-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/p6/0v0bflxn3t399_qdpnm2z7hc0000gn/T/pip-record-ihy3we/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/vaibhavmule/Envs/switchidea/bin/../include/site/python2.7/MySQL-python:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7
    clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:36:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
    #include "my_config.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/vaibhavmule/Envs/switchidea/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import 
setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/p6/0v0bflxn3t399_qdpnm2z7hc0000gn/T/pip-install-SD9Cgh/MySQL-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/p6/0v0bflxn3t399_qdpnm2z7hc0000gn/T/pip-record-ihy3we/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/vaibhavmule/Envs/switchidea/bin/../include/site/python2.7/MySQL-python" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/p6/0v0bflxn3t399_qdpnm2z7hc0000gn/T/pip-install-SD9Cgh/MySQL-python/
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I just resolved this exact issue when running Ansible's [mysql_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mysql_user_module.html) module. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43740481/python-setup-py-egg-info-mysqlclient) helped tip me off to a solution. I also needed `MySQL-python` from `pip`, which also broke in this process, so I've added the extra steps.

Steps to resolve:

1. `brew unlink mysql # only if installed, causes the next step to fail`
2. `brew install mysql-connector-c`
3. locate `mysql_config` file with `which (mysql_config)`
4. edit the `mysql_config` file, under `# Create options` change this:

   `libs="$libs -l "`

   to this:

   `libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"`

   if using vim, `:wq!` to save the read-only file
5. Now the install should run successfully

   `pip install mysqlclient`
6. Adding this separately, as it's similar but not directly related to the initial question

   `pip install MySQL-python`
7. Fix `mysql` brew formula, if it was unlinked in the first step.

   `brew unlink mysql-connector-c`

   `brew link mysql`

Comment: Along with I need to link `mysql-connector-c` like `brew link mysql-connector-c`

Comment: It is still failing at step 5 for me.
So I install openssl by `brew install openssl` and then I set ssl library path explicitly `LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysqlclient` and now it's working.

Comment: import MySQLdb throws an error "this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 4, 2, 'post', 1)" anyways

Comment: Just a note for a different MacOS version (namely Catalina 10.15.0 and mysql 8.0.18), there is no need to perform any additional steps. Just `brew install mysql` and `mysql_config` should be visible by default, as it is located at `/usr/local/bin` (that's assuming `/usr/local/bin` is part of your PATH environment variable)

Comment: For me, step 4 (updating options in mysql_config) was not necessary, as those options were already there. I had to add `mysql-client` to my path after step 2 before the `pip install mysqlclient` would work however: `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: UPDATE: If you have Linux/Mac: Please open the /usr/local/bin/mysql_config.

Answer (score 20):

I fixed it by passing the OpenSSL path:

```
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install mysqlclient
```

[You can see the full article of the solution done by MrWeeble](https://medium.com/@MrWeeble/homebrew-on-mac-and-pythons-mysqlclient-ea44fa300e70)

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by setting xcode-select to use non-XCode command line tools, as shown in the below answer. I had a related `clang` error which led me to this answer.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30902106/11614142

Comment: Nice catch! Was causing all kinds of other issues for me. Prevents you having to use the flag in the comments above.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I was running into this issue while trying to pip install dbt.  This worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I know maybe the former answers can solve the problem already. But I'm still sharing below solution. If you don't want to brew install any extra things, you can try this solution.

I think the issue happens in many situations, mainly related to the installation of the pip packages about MySQL. In my case, I bumped into this issue when trying to install mysqlclient for Django.

This solution should work when you've installed MySQL with dmg downloaded from their official site.

In that case, you may find `mysql_config` in `/usr/local/mysql/bin`

If so, add `export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:${PATH}"` in `~/.bash_profile`, this would add the `bin` folder of mysql into the PATH, or you can say *environment variable*. Please note that `mysql` maybe in detail with your mysql version. In my case, the path is `/usr/local/mysql-8.0.12-macos10.13-x86_64/bin`.

Save and close the file, then `source ~/.bash_profile` to enable the change.

Try to install the pip package about MySQL again.

If still not working, a restart is preferred.

Comment: Similarly, if you've used brew to install mysql_client, you may have to add ```/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin``` to the path

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers are really needed in that length. As Vishal noted it is as easy as

```
brew install openssl 
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysqlclient
```

Then go back to install your `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 1):

So first what is `clang`? it is a "compiler frontend" for C, C++. What is a compiler frontend you may ask? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24836566/3823815) for more details. You're trying to install a library (`mysqlclient` or `apache-airflow[mysql]` or any other) that requires *some* C++ dependency to be found but is not, hence the message that looks like:

```
    #include "my_config.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The `clang` error messages are pretty verbose so you might miss the important information. What's important are those 3 lines:

```
    ld: library not found for -lzstd
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Find that first line before "command 'clang' failed", this will tell you what library was not found.

If the library was not found, it could be because it's not installed (hence all the `brew install ...` answers here) or because it's not found in the path (hence all the `export LDFLAGS=...` and `export LIBRARY_PATH=...` answers).

In my case, 2 librairies were not found but both were installed, so I solved it with:

```sh
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1l/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/zstd/1.5.0/lib"
pip install 'apache-airflow[mysql]'
```

This is not a direct answer to OP, but hopefully helpful in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this,

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

Then re-execute the installation command. It's resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following did the trick for me, Using mac.

```
brew install leveldb gmp pkg-config
```

After this just run

```
pip3 install MySQL-python
```